# Set navigator min zoom

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to set the min zoom (max range) of my chart. Basically I'm trying to do the opposite of the minRange property. I'm struggling for a while with this problem. I have a "[solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Teles/4k1ubzto/)", but I don't like it, this solution allow the user to choose a range greater then the "max range", and immediately correct it.

> **POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

```
$(function() {

    var lastMin;
    var lastMax;
    var maxRange = 12 * 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000; //12 month

    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        scrollbar: {
            liveRedraw: false
        },

        xAxis: {
            events: {
                afterSetExtremes: function(e) {
                    var max = this.max,
                        min = this.min;

                    if (lastMin && lastMax) {
                        if(max-min > maxRange) {
                            if (min < lastMin) {
                                min = max - maxRange;
                            } else {
                                max = min + maxRange;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    var x = this;
                    setTimeout(function(){ 
                        x.setExtremes(min,max); //chart xAxis
                    }, 1);

                    lastMin = min;
                    lastMax = max;
                }
            }
        },
        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'USD to EUR',
            data: usdeur
        }]
    });
});
```

I want to block the user from choosing a range greater than the allowed, in other words, block the navigator when it's too big

I'm also following this [issue](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2017), I tried all the proposed solution, but I'm having errors ("Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined")

Comment: This is the simplest way, but in your scenario, you need to [wrap](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts) highstock scroller.mouseMoveHandler function.

Comment: Thanks! Wrapping the fuction I managed to do exactly what I wanted =).

Comment: Sounds great, so all works properly I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Sebastian!

I managed to find a  solution ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Teles/4k1ubzto/1/)) wrapping the "render" function. Doing that I managed to really set a "min zoom" on the navigator bar.

```
    $(function() {

    var lastX0;
    var lastX1;
    var maxRange = 100; //100 pixels

    (function (H) {       
        H.wrap(H.Scroller.prototype, 'render', function (proceed) {    
            console.log(arguments)
            if(arguments[4] - arguments[3] > maxRange + 2) {
                if (arguments[3] < lastX0) {
                    arguments[3] = lastX0;
                } else {
                    arguments[4] = lastX1;
                }
            }
            proceed.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));

            lastX0 = arguments[3];
            lastX1 = arguments[4];
        });
    }(Highcharts));  

    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        scrollbar: {
            liveRedraw: true
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'USD to EUR',
            data: usdeur
        }]
    });


    var highchart = $('#container').highcharts();
    var extremes = highchart.xAxis[0].getExtremes();
    var rangeTotal = extremes.max - extremes.min;

    var f = maxRange / $('#container').width();
    highchart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(extremes.max - (f * rangeTotal), extremes.max);
});
```

In the sample code I'm used a fixed amount of pixels, but in my real application i'm making it dynamic. I making this, because I can't use the data grouping property in the software that I'm working, and since the minimum size of a bar in a chart is 1 pixel (obviously) highcharts hide some bars (or points).

I'm setting the minimum zoom so all bar in the displayed range are visible , since the user can't display a higher range in the x Axis the "hidden" bar "problem" (is an awesome feature, but I can't make use of it) won't happen